# Apply a proxy using traits

Tags: raku

I'd like to write a trait for an attribute that gives it a proxy so that I can manipulate the values behind the seens even for `$!direct-access` within a class.

This is what I have right now, but as you can see, the actual get/set or store/fetch methods are never called.  I'm probably not applying them correctly, but the only examples I've found have what looks like tons of extra code that are doing way more than I need but I can't isolate the important bits.

```
# The below shows on a Str more or less how I'd expect things to work
# although the %data wouldn't be hard coded of course

my Str $localized := do {
  my %data = hi => "hola", bye => "adiós";
  my $str  = "";
  Proxy.new:
    :STORE{ $str = @_[1] },
    :FETCH{ with %data{$str} { $_ } else { $str } }
}

$localized = "hi";
say $localized;
$localized = "bye";
say $localized;
$localized = "not defined";
say $localized;

# This seems to almost work, 

multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute:D $a, :$localized!) {

  say $a.container.VAR.WHAT;

  $a.container.VAR does role Localized {
    has $!str;
    method STORE($a) { say "store!"; $!str = $a }
    method FETCH {say "fetch!"}
  }
}


class Foo {
  has Str $.text is localized;
}

my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo.text, " <-- should be in Spanish";
$foo.text = "bye";
say $foo.text, " <-- should be in Spanish";
```

Although in this case the `STORE` method is called correctly, the fetch method is not, and the gist of `$foo.text` is `Scalar+{Localized}.new`, which shows I'm not quite applying things correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to arrange for the `Proxy` to be *bound* into the attribute, so that there's a `Proxy` there rather than a `Scalar` container that is usually created by class initialization logic. This could be achieved by setting build logic (although you'll be overriding any initial default value if taking this approach), and using that to bind the attribute to a new `Proxy` at each object creation:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Attribute:D $a, :$localized!) {
    $a.set_build: -> \SELF, | {
        $a.set_value: SELF, Proxy.new:
            STORE => -> $, $val { say "store $val" },
            FETCH => { say "fetch!"; 42 }
    }
}
```

This then will call the `FETCH` and `STORE` callbacks (noting that `FETCH` may be called for internal reasons, such as type checks, as well as those accesses that you directly see):

```
class C {
    has $.attr is localized is rw;
}
my $c = C.new;
$c.attr = 'foo';
my $x = $c.attr;
```

This example demonstrates that it functions on attribute reads inside of the class too:

```
class C {
    has $.attr is localized is rw;

    method m() {
        $!attr = 'foo';
        my $x = $!attr
    }
}
C.new.m;
```

Comment: @certainperformance how exactly did my edit change the intent of jnthn's answer? It actually lines his answer up with the stated intent (shown via my original code, and in the literal first line: *I'd like to write a trait for an attribute that gives it a proxy so that I can **manipulate the values behind the seens** [sic]*).  I'm fairly confident that this was a minor oversight on his part (since knowing him he quickly punched out an answer right before bed), as the entire rest of the question (the harder stuff) was in his answer