# Apply a proxy to a variable (not an attribute) using traits

Tags: raku, rakudo

This question is a near-duplicate of [Apply a proxy using traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734126/apply-a-proxy-using-traits).  However, that question dealt with applying a proxy to an Attribute, and I would like to do the same thing for a Variable.  From Jonathan's answer, I understand that I

> need to arrange for the Proxy to be bound into the attribute, so that there's a Proxy there rather than a Scalar container that is usually created by class initialization logic.

However, I can't seem to bind successfully to a Variable:D, even at compile time. (Including with nqp::bind).  I'd greatly appreciate any pointers in the correct direction.

(Ideally, I'd like to support using the variable/trait with assignment syntax.  In a perfect world, I'd have syntax like:

```
my $thing is custom-proxy = 42;
```

And the result of that would be that `$thing` is containerized inside the Proxy, but *not* in a Scalar.  But if that's not possible, I'd settle for getting it working with binding via `:=`.

[**EDIT**: building on the accepted answer below, it is possible to *mostly* do this with the following code:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable \v, :$tom) {
    v.block.add_phaser(
        'ENTER',
        v.willdo(<-> $_ {
            $_ = Proxy.new:
                     STORE => -> $, $v { say "store $v" },
                     FETCH => { say "fetch!"; 42}
                }, 1))
}
```

This works for variables that are not initialized to a different value or for `state` variables on calls to the function other than the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My 2d<sup>**[1]**</sup>:

> I'd settle for getting it working with binding via `:=`.

```
sub custom-proxy is rw { Proxy.new: FETCH => { 42 }, STORE => { ... } }
my $variable := custom-proxy;
say $variable; # 42
```

> In a perfect world, I'd have syntax like:

```
my $thing is custom-proxy = 42;
```

Aiui, that's @Larry's intent.

But, as you presumably know, if a type (eg `role custom-proxy { ... }`) is applied using an `is` trait to a *scalar* variable (eg `my $variable is custom-proxy`) then the compiler emits a compile time error message (`is trait on $-sigil variable not yet implemented`).

> I can't seem to bind successfully to a `Variable:D`, even at compile time

First, let's clarify what a [`Variable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Variable) is, and what you would need to successfully bind to:

```
multi trait_mod:<is>(Variable \var, :$foo!) { say var.var.VAR.WHAT } # (Scalar)
my $variable is foo;
```

You might think you could bind to `var`. But the compiler is passing an lvalue, so you're not going to be able to alter it.

You might think you could bind to `var.var`, which is an attribute of a `Variable`. (I explain what a `Variable` is, and its `var` attribute, and why I had to write "varvarVAR!" in the above code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55972492/1077672).)

The SO you linked shows how to alter the value bound to an attribute in some object:

```
$a.set_build: -> \SELF, | {
  $a.set_value: SELF, Proxy.new:
    STORE => -> $, $val { say "store $val" },
    FETCH => { say "fetch!"; 42 }
}
```

So perhaps you could use that approach to alter the `.var` attribute of a `Variable`?

Unfortunately, "setting build logic" is used to "bind the attribute ... **at each object creation**", (hence "you'll be overriding any initial default value").

So I don't think this technique is going to help in this case because the `Variable`, and hence its `.var` attribute, has presumably already been built by the time the `Variable` is passed to the `is` trait.

In summary, while a trait *is* called at compile-time, I think it's called *too late* because the `var` attribute has already been permanently bound.

---

My guess is that altering Raku(do) so that the `Variable`'s `.var` attribute becomes writable, or using metaprogramming to dive underneath `Variable`'s public API to force through a change, would be beyond fraught, unreasonably complicating the compiler's variable handling code and/or swapping out codegen optimization logic for pessimization logic.

This may be behind @Larry's speculation that a more controlled `is type` on scalar variables will one day be implemented.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> My two (pennies | dogecoin).

Answer (score 5):

You can always bind.

```raku
my $actual-thing = 42;

my $thing := Proxy.new(
    FETCH => anon method fetch () {
        say 'fetch';
        $actual-thing
    },
    STORE => anon method store ($new) {
        say 'store ',$new;
        $actual-thing = $new
    }
);

say $thing;
$thing = 5;
say $thing;
```

Which currently results in the following.

```
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
42
store 5
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
fetch
5
```

(The repeated `FETCH` calls are a known limitation.)

---

If you wanted to have syntax like

```raku
my $thing is custom-proxy = 42;
```

You would need to start with

```raku
multi trait_mod:<is> ( Variable:D \var, :$custom-proxy! ){
    …
}
```

The problem is that currently doing it this way requires a lot of deep Rakudo/nqp knowledge that I do not possess.

For example the code behind `my $var is default('value')` looks a bit like this:

```raku
multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Variable:D $v, Mu :$default!) {
    my $var  := $v.var;
    my $what := $var.VAR.WHAT;

    my $descriptor;
    {
        $descriptor := nqp::getattr($var, $what.^mixin_base, '$!descriptor');
        CATCH {
            my $native = $v.native($what);
            …
        }
    }
    …
    $descriptor.set_default(nqp::decont($default));

    # make sure we start with the default if a scalar
    $var = $default if nqp::istype($what, Scalar);
}
```

Why does that have `$what.^mixin_base`?
I have no idea.

Why isn't `$!descriptor` accessible something like `$v.var.descriptor`?
I have no idea.

How do we change `$v.var.VAR` from a `Scalar` to a `Proxy`?
I have no idea.

Is that last one doable? (From within a `trait_mod:<is>`)
I am fairly certain that the answer is yes.